# how to program a true cuda

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda

i'am taking a course in Advanced artificial intelligence,and i must learn CUDA programming,and i saw in many website cuda examples,but i'am confused about something.my professor told me that cuda is similar to c but no for loops for example
and in all the documentation i open from Nvidia and other website i only can see CUDA C example.so what i want to understand where to start programming CUDA not CUDA C or CUDA C++.

also is there's any reference which helps me to start from scratch.like how to declare variables.how to print on screen how the structure of the program.how to make a function how to make loop w.r.t CUDA not the for loop of the C ore C++ Language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would have look harder, you would have found out that CUDA isn't a programming language (like C or C++). CUDA is the platform of parallel programming for the NVIDIA cards. CUDA C++ or CUDA C are alternatives for you, so you can use CUDA(platform of parallel programming for the NVIDIA cards). There is also pyCUDA for example, so you could take advantage of CUDA through python. The programming language is up to you.

If you just want to code CUDA through examples, there is plenty in the internet, and yes, you have to search for CUDA C or CUDA C++. But if you want to understand the platform, and also code, I recommend two books: the one with a lot of examples, and from NVIDIA: [CUDA by Example](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/books/cuda-by-example/cuda-by-example-sample.pdf) and the other is [Programming Massively Parallel Processors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123814723) for a more detailed and well-explained book.

Comment: As already stated, CUDA is not a separate language by itself.  CUDA represents extensions to C, C++, Fortran or many other languages (Python, Java, etc.) that allow you to program GPUs. So you will have to pick a language.  The NVIDIA [CUDA C programmers guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) is a very readable document if you're familiar with C.

Comment: Also, NVIDIA provides [webinars](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/gpu-computing-webinars) that you can watch any time to get started.  [This](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/cudaintrowebinar.mp4) is a good first webinar, and [this](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_Webinars_CUDA_Memory_Optimization.wmv) is a good second webinar for C programmers.

Comment: OK that's helpful but.so i knew c and c++ and they contains for loop.but as i mentioned that the professor told us no for loops .i just need explanation to this point.

Comment: It's very difficult to really explain that, but i'll try. A lot of times, for loops make the same work for all the iterations, for example you have an  int array and add +1 to every values in the array, so normally you need a for loop, but with CUDA, you could tell the graphic card to do that in time 1. Because the GPU can deploy all the threads you want and every thread will add +1 to its respective value in the array, so thread 0 will work with array[0], thread 1 with array[1], thread 2 with array[2], etc.

Comment: yes i'am sorry i didn't search well before asking the question but because i'am new in CUDA i was a afraid to open any wrong door and waste time ,that's why i asked for advice.....sorry